# MongoDB query to C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I convert the following query to C# in order to return the arraylist in a REST request?
I could prepare this query in mongoDB but I don't know how to run it into my C# API.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$status"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$status.Origin",
      Total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      Country: "$_id",
      Total: 1,
      Started: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$data",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.status.Detail",
                "Started"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      Received: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$data",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.status.Detail",
                "Received"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The coda above returns an array and the result I will use to fill a chart.